# JUnit tests fails on GitHub Actions but not locally

Tags: java, junit, jvm, github-actions

I am trying to run JUnit tests on GitHub Actions but some of it fails. Locally all tests passed. On my PC I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with OpenJDK 1.8 (275), on CI using OpenJDK 1.8 (from standard actions).

`java -version` output from PC:

```sh
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_275-8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~20.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
```

`java-version` output from GitHub Actions:

```sh
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.50.0.53-CA-linux64) (build 1.8.0_275-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.50.0.53-CA-linux64) (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
```

Test assertion:

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    assertEquals(
        17,
        new CountingSheep(
            new Boolean[]{
                true, true, true, false,
                true, true, true, true,
                true, false, true, false,
                true, false, false, true,
                true, true, true, true,
                false, false, true, true
            }
        ).solution()
    );
}
```

Code:

```java
package com.smlnskgmail.jaman.codewarsjava.kyu8;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class CountingSheep {

    private final Boolean[] input;

    public CountingSheep(Boolean[] input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public int solution() {
        return (int) Arrays
                .stream(input, 0, input.length)
                .filter(b -> b != null && b)
                .count();
    }

}
```

CI checks fails with:

```sh
com.smlnskgmail.jaman.codewarsjava.kyu8.CountingSheepTest > test FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<17> but was:<0>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:645)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:631)
        at com.smlnskgmail.jaman.codewarsjava.kyu8.CountingSheepTest.test(CountingSheepTest.java:11)
```

JUnit implementation:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

GitHub Actions config:

```yaml
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

env:
  GRADLE_OPTS: -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew build --info
```

But this test passed month ago and I am cannot change code.

Repository with code: https://github.com/fartem/codewars-java

SOLUTION: [here](https://github.com/fartem/codewars-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/smlnskgmail/jaman/codewarsjava/kyu4/Bagels.java) is the class with reflection from the project. Without execute this class all tests are passed.

Comment: Did you step through the code in your IDE? Where is the `CountingSheep` constructor?

Comment: Has the Gradle version changed since the last time the test passed? Or perhaps the version of Java 1.8 Check the `actions/virtual-environments` repository for Ubuntu to see the changelog.

Comment: Gradle the same as version month ago (when all tests passed). In the question I am added `java -version` outputs from the PC and from GitHub Actions.

Comment: BTW Could those who downvoted please give a reason? The problem is far away from being trivial, the poster has shown own effords, he has provided everything he asked for so far.

Comment: It's worth downloading the Azul Zulu version so that you're running with exactly the same version, or running it locally in a Docker container that does the same thing. The code looks like it should be the same in both places, but clearly the resulting code's count is returning zero. It might be worth putting in some print statements so that you can verify your code is being called as you expect.

Comment: @AlBlue Yes, I'm planing do it on local machine.

Comment: Those wishing to look further -- the source repository appears to be here https://github.com/fartem/codewars-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it was an error on GitHub. The tests appear to pass, and I created a fork with just that test at https://github.com/fartem/codewars-java/pull/1 which seemed to pass successfully.

Given the only thing that's changed is the version of Java materialised with your checkout action, I wonder whether or not GitHub had a temporarily broken version of Java that was rolled back.

By the way, you're using an array of `Boolean` in the test, but in this case you could use an array of `boolean` instead -- that way, your filter wouldn't need to have the `b != null` check there.

--

As per fartem's observation, there was an additional piece of code that ran and changed the value of `Boolean.TRUE` to `false`. The variation was a random ordering of the tests.

```
 Field field = Boolean.class.getField("TRUE");
 field.setAccessible(true);

 Field modifiedField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
 modifiedField.setAccessible(true);
 modifiedField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

 field.set(null, false);
```

So any tests that used auto-boxing on Boolean after this test had run would get the wrong results.

Comment: Problem with [this](https://github.com/fartem/codewars-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/smlnskgmail/jaman/codewarsjava/kyu4/Bagels.java) class with Boolean reflection. Thank you for your advice to check all classes.

Comment: Ooh, that's going to be nasty :) Might be better to try and use that code without changing `Boolean`, or perhaps instead create a new instance of Boolean and then use the final approach for the instance field with that specific instance, so you don't poison your code elsewhere.

Comment: In my case maybe is just a wrong tests execution order.

Comment: If you run the tests in the same JVM, then any test executed after your change-the-value-of-Boolean-TRUE test is going to potentially break. You won't be able to guarantee test ordering. This may be why you had an issue with it on GitHub (which used the gradle daemon) but not seen when you execute the code locally (if it ran one JVM per test, or ran them in a different order).